# SQLite insert record with _id value for two or more fields

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I have a case that I would like to insert record in SQLite with database.insert(table, null, values).

```
TABLE t2 (_id, field1, field2)
..

val.setVal1(null);
val.setVal2(val2);
..

if(val.getVal1==null){
  values.put(field1, _id);
}else{
    values.put(field1, var.val1);
}
values.put(field2, var.val2);

database.insert("t2", null, values);
```

Is possible to do sth like this "values.put(field1, _id);"?
_id is generated at database.insert().

**Note:** I am looking for solution for one insert call. Insert and update row with (field1=_id) is easy.

Comment: not quite sure what you're actually asking. You might wanna explain your goal a bit better.

Comment: `field1`, `val1`, `var`, `values` this are generic words that prevent me from understanding your code... maybe you try to use some real life samples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i see now. you're asking if you can enter a value into a specific SQLite row `_id` field **if** it's available in your `val` object. Else, you want the database to automatically create a unique id for that column while inserting, like normally done. Is this correct?

To that end, i would seriously reconsider this purpose. You should never be specifying values for the `_id` column because it needs to be unique or else you'll get exceptions thrown. Moreover, it's only purpose is to be a unique identifier for the system, so you personally knowing this value should be of no use to you.

If you still need this functionality, i'd suggest making another field in your table (much like the `_id` column but **not** it), which you can fill with randomly generated numbers or `val.getVal1` values.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But this is more about "field1". If "val.getVal1==null" I want to insert "_id" value to "field1". And "_id" value is generated on database.insert(...) call. This is the main question, if is possible to execute this with one database.insert(...) call.

Comment: yes it is possible. as you know the `insert` method returns the `long` id that has been created upon inserting. so you only need to give the variable a name and then you can do whatever you need with it. ex. `lond id = database.insert("t2", null, values); val.setVal1(id);`

Comment: This is normal procedure. And to store "id" in "field1" I would call database.update(...). But this means insert() and update() call. My question is, is this possible in one database.insert(...)

Comment: no, this is not possible. for that id to be made, that insert command needs to come first and return the value. for what you want, you'd have to make your own SQLite core method (which i don't recommend). But.. why would you need another field in your database have exactly the same value? and what's stopping you from performing the mere two lines of code it would take to do what you intended?

Comment: Now I know this is not possible. If I remember correctly this is possible in MSSQL. One line is important for code optimization and because DB functions burn a lot of device resources.